# Axios API get request with Redux not able to pass in variable in action

Tags: javascript, react-native, redux, axios

I'm trying to pass in a variable into an axios request in my action:

```
export function searchRequest(search){
    return(dispatch)=>{
        console.log('in search', search)
        return axios.get(`http://localhost:4000/reports/${search}`)
                .then(response => {

                    dispatch(searchInfo(response.data))
                })
    }
}
```

When I console log search, it does not register.

However, when I remove the return dispatch and console log response.data in the .then, I get the desired data, but I'm not able to use dispatch.

The question is, why am I not able to pass in search in this way?

Edit: this is in react native

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how you connect this function to Redux in React-native but I think it works like you're doing it with regular React.
The `searchRequest` function return a new function with one variable `dispatch`. `search` will be "static" with the value you've passed in when calling `searchRequest`, so probably null or undefined or some hardcoded value.
You should to this the other way around:

```
import {connect} from 'react-redux'

const searchRequest = (dispatch) => {
   return async (search) => {
      const response = await axios.get(`http://localhost:4000/reports/${search}`)
      dispatch(searchInfo(response.data))
   }
}

class YourComponent extends Component {
....
  onSearch = (search) => {
     this.props.doSearch(search)
  }
....
}

const mapDispatch = (dispatch) => ({
  doSearch: searchRequest(dispatch)
})

export connect(null, mapDispatch)(YourComponent)
```

This is how it looks with "normal  web"-React. Maybe in native it looks different. Notice that dispatch is provided as parameter once. Afterwards when calling `doSearch` the same instance of dispatch is used inside the function.